# Why this RegEx is not working in PHP?

Tags: php, preg-split

First, I know I can get the very same result with explode, just want to know why it is not working in PHP

```
preg_split('/(.+,)+(.+)/im', 'New York, NY, United States');
```

It returns

```
array (
  0 => '',
  1 => '',
)
```

Why? It should returns: `['New York, NY, ', 'United States']` right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using preg_split you can make :

`preg_split("/,\s/", 'New York, NY, United States');`

This function needs the pattern of the separator.

Comment: This is not giving the array given by OP ie. `['New York, NY, ', 'United States']` that have only two elements.

Comment: With preg_split the 'limit' parameter set to default value '-1' will return all the 3 results on array.

Comment: In OP's question the array is TWO element long, 1rst is `New York, NY, ` the second one is `United States`

Answer (score 1):

You are actually doing a match for what you want, not on what you want to use to split:

```
preg_match('/(.*,)+ (.*)/', $subject, $result);
```

would get the matches in `$result`

**note**: I've added a space and removed the multi line modifiers, there are not needed in your case.

If you want to use preg split, you need to use a negative lookahead to get the last `,`:

```
preg_split('/(,)(?!.*,)/i', 'New York, NY, United States');
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the array: `['New York, NY, ', 'United States']`, remove the second quantifier and use preg_match instead:

```
preg_match('/^(.+,)(.+?)$/im', 'New York, NY, United States', $match);
```